# No matching constructor for initialisation of const std::shared_ptr<>

Tags: c++, c++17, shared-ptr

**Scenario**
I am using *C++ 17* on *MacOS* with *clang* as compiler. I have a few classes which are initialised in a certain order demonstrated in sample code below

Firstly, `SomeClass` which is very simple and almost a dummy for the example sake.

**SomeClass.h**

```
SomeClass {

public:
    SomeClass() { }
}
```

Lets say below is `ClassA` like this .

**ClassA.h**

```
ClassA {

public:
    ClassA(const std::shared_ptr<SomeClass> & some_class);

private:
    std::shared_ptr<SomeClass> m_some_class;
}
```

**ClassA.cpp**

```
ClassA::ClassA(const std::shared_ptr<SomeClass> & some_class) : m_some_class(some_class) {

}
```

Note above that `ClassA` intakes a `const std::shared_ptr<SomeClass> &` type into its constructor and stores it as its member.

Next there is `ClassB` which has private member of `ClassA` as `std::shared_ptr`. And all I want to do is to initialise `m_class_a` by passing it the required `const std::shared_ptr<SomeClass> &` which `ClassA` needs to init its member.

**ClassB.h**

```
ClassB {

public:
    ClassB(const std::shared_ptr<SomeClass> & some_class);

private:
    std::shared_ptr<ClassA> m_class_a;
}
```

**ClassB.cpp**

```
ClassB::ClassB(const std::shared_ptr<SomeClass> & some_class) : m_class_a(some_class) {

}
// Above constructor throws compiler error complaining "No matching constructor for initialisation of `std::shared_ptr<SomeClass>`"
```

And finally, heres my `main.cpp` which only wants to initialise `ClassB`

**main.cpp**

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])

    auto some_cass = std::make_shared<SomeClass>();
    ClassB object_b(some_class);
    return 0;
}
```

**Question:**
What is wrong with what I am doing above and what is reason for this compiler error? How can I resolve the issue?

**Secondary question:**
What would change if in `ClassB`, instead of having `std::shared_ptr<ClassA> m_class_a` as member, I would have had `ClassA & m_class_a` as member?

Comment: What's really unclear about the compiler error message?

Comment: Well. I am passing a `const std::shared_ptr<SomeClass> &` into another construction which also accepts a `const std::shared_ptr<SomeClass> &`. Both are same types. why does the compiler complain? i don't understand. I am not saying compiler is wrong but curious to understand the reason.

Comment: Provide a [MCVE] as required, and maybe someone can give you a concise answer.

Comment: how is  `SomeClass` constructor looks like? and where is the initialization bit of the `someclass` before passing it to classA as reference to a shared pointer.

Comment: Note that `m_class_a` needs the `const std::shared_ptr<SomeClass> &` to initialise itself. `const std::shared_ptr<SomeClass> &` is just propagated from `ClassA` to `ClassB`. Thats all is logic/goal.

Comment: @Yucel_K How does `SomeClass` construction matter? Lets say `SomeClass` is the same kind of dummy class like `ClassA` that is initialised in `main.cpp`. I can update question with that if neessary

Comment: No, `SomeClass` doesn't matter. But what object ends up using this instance of `SomeClass` does, and it can only be a `ClassA`. And you can only create a new one. Or you pass a `ClassA` directly.

Comment: i just want to understsand the full code. you passing `someclass` from somewhere to either `ClassA` or `ClassB` dont you. so where is that bit of the code? besides your compiler complaining about a constructor. so it maybe related

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I have now provided the complete code with all the classes including main.cpp. Sorry to have missed to explain the scenario clearly.

Comment: @Game_Of_Threads Well, that's nice and required here.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I would love to have the negative voting :-( gone from the question since I have provided the complete code and it is genuine issue which needs explanation :-(

Comment: @Game_Of_Threads I am not going to discuss that further with you. There's plenty of information about that already [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ reading through the link to improve my questions in future. I am correcting this one to make the point clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that you are trying to initialize a variable with type `std::shared_ptr<ClassA>` but you are giving it a `std::shared_ptr<SomeClass>`. They are incompatible.

Are you trying to create a new `ClassA`? In that case, the constructor should be:

```
ClassB::ClassB(const std::shared_ptr<SomeClass> & some_class)
: m_class_a(std::make_shared<ClassA>(some_class))
{}
```

Comment: `std::make_shared(some_class)` is this correct? I don't think so

Comment: Note that `m_class_a` needs the `const std::shared_ptr<SomeClass> &` to initialise itself. `const std::shared_ptr<SomeClass> &` is just propagated from `ClassA` to `ClassB`. Thats all is logic/goal.

Comment: It is, as I've said, I'm creating a new `ClassA`, because only a new `ClassA` can consume a `SomeClass`. Where is this shared pointer going to go otherwise? So I'n creating a new `ClassA` and then it propagates the `SomeClass` shared pointer through its constructor.

Comment: Please correct answer. it should be `std::make_shared<ClassA>(some_class)` not `std::make_shared(some_class)`

Comment: Yes indeed. Obviously missing the type!

Comment: BTW, `main.cpp` doesn't use the constructor with the `shared_ptr`, hence the confusion in the other answers.